# Motivation for time dilation in a gravitational field

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

I am taking a course on GR and in introducing GR from SR, the professor makes the following argument:

Between SR and GR, the line elements are given as follows:

$ds^2_{SR} = \eta_{ab}dx^adx^b$

$ds^2_{GR} = g_{ab}(t,\vec{x})dx^adx^b$

Now, with gravity in the picture, if we expand this line element in two separate frames, even if the spatial differences in both frames are zero i.e even if $ d\vec{x}^2 = 0 = d\vec{x'}^2$ we must have:

$ds^2 = g_{ab}(t,\vec{x})dt = g_{ab}(t,\vec{x'})dt'$

And since in general we can have $g_{ab}(t,\vec{x}) \neq g_{ab}(t,\vec{x'})$, we must have $dt \neq dt'$ just due to the presence of a gravitational field.

However, I fail to understand why the line element itself must be invariant between frames in GR, just because it is so in SR. For instance, as I understand it, the position four vector (whose components are) $x^{\mu}$ are Lorentz invariant in SR but not so in GR.

So why do we assume that the line elements must be invariant between two reference frames?

Comment: The invariance of the line element is a fundamental assumption in GR. SR inherits the invariance of the line element from GR since the Minkowski metric is one of the vacuum solutions we get from solving Einstein's equation.

Answer (score 0):

As John Rennie explained in the comment, the invariance of the line element is a fundamental assumption of GR. Mathematically, the equation for the line element you have is invariant under any general coordinate transformation because the metric tensor and the local differentials transforms under the coordinate transformation in a way that they cancel out so that the line element remains the same. A general coordinate transformation includes local shift in time, too.

Indeed, you can assume that the line element can change by something or anything and make a new hypothesis to predict new things that no one even ever thought about. In this case, your hypothesis must get through harsh test of nature or experiment.